# Python - Plot multiple dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

I have a dataframe with 4 columns and I want to do a groupby and plot the data. But I am not sure how to go about this.

```
    Cont       Coun     X3   Y1
    Africa    nigeria   A    10
    Africa    nigeria   B    93
    Africa    nigeria   C    124
    Africa    nigeria   D    24
 -------------------------------
    Africa    kenya     A    123
    Africa    kenya     B    540
    Africa    kenya     C    1000
    Africa    kenya     D    183
 --------------------------------
    Asia      Japan     A    1234
    Asia      Japan     B    820
    Asia      Japan     C    2130
    Asia      Japan     D    912
```

For every distinct continent(cont) and country(coun) pair, plot 4 different bars corresponding to the column X3. The Y1 column is the Y-axis

Result:-
[image]

Comment: `I am not sure how to go about this` - seems like you know what you want to do - `groupby and plot` - have you spent any time with the Pandas Docs or Tutorials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend `seaborn` for this kind of plots:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.barplot(df.Cont+'\n'+df.Coun, 'Y1', hue='X3', data=df)
```

[image]

---

For adjusting figure size you can create a figure with a subplot first and then put the seaborn plot into the desired destination with the `ax` kwarg:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 8))
sns.barplot(df.Cont+'\n'+df.Coun, 'Y1', hue='X3', data=df, ax=ax)
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. However, I used a subset of my data for this question and when I apply this to the full data, the barplot is very small and squashed together. How do I increase the size of the plot thank you

Comment: The easiest way would be to initially create a matplotlib axes object, where you are completely free to define size and other parameters, even if it is perhaps a subplot among others etc. Then you can set the axes where to plot your barplot in with the `ax` kwarg of `sns.barplot`. See also my edit.